# iOS: UIActivityIndicator does not keeps distance from bottom with springs&struts

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to set an `UIActivityIndicator` on the screen that must keep same distance from the bottom of the screen (for 3.5 and 4 inch iPhones). The `UIActivityIndicator` will be placed as a `subView` of a `blockerView` which has the purpose to block user interaction.

Here is my code, but it does not work:

```
_blockerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: self.view.window.bounds];
[_blockerView setAutoresizingMask: ( UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth |                       UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight)];
[self.view addSubview: _blockerView];
_activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150, 338, 20, 20)];
[_blockerView addSubview:_activityIndicator];
[_activityIndicator setAutoresizingMask: UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin];
[_activityIndicator startAnimating];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your issue is that it's a different distance from the bottom on a 4 inch compared to 3.5 inch screen, you need to do your initial calculations from the bottom, yours are currently from the top.

When a view controller is created its view's size defaults to that of the screen. Because in your setup you do an initial Y position of 338, and your view controller's view's size probably doesn't change again, the bottom margin will be different.

Instead try this (calculating from the bottom)

```
_blockerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
[_blockerView setAutoresizingMask:(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight)];
[self.view addSubview:_blockerView];

_activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] init];

CGRect activityIndictatorFrame = CGRectZero;
activityIndictatorFrame.size = [_activityIndicator sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];
activityIndictatorFrame.origin.x = floorf((_blockerView.frame.size.width - activityIndictatorFrame.size.width) / 2.0);  //  X: centered
activityIndictatorFrame.origin.y = _blockerView.frame.size.height - activityIndictatorFrame.size.height - 116;  //  Y: fixed from bottom

[_activityIndicator setFrame:activityIndictatorFrame];
[_activityIndicator setAutoresizingMask:(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin)];
[_blockerView addSubview:_activityIndicator];

[_activityIndicator startAnimating];
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution! Sadly, I don't have enough reputation to rate you. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough points yet to comment on SomeGuy's answer, so I will propose an answer.

Calculating the Y position of the activityIndicator frame relative to the bottom of the screen does not matter, since the calculation is evaluated before it is assigned to CGRectMake. So it makes no difference if it's a fixed number or any statement.

Assuming 'self' is a UIViewController instance, you will get into trouble using self.view.window.bounds:

1. The window may not even exist at the time you call self.view.window (e.g. inside viewDidLoad)
2. Your view controller's bounds do not always have to equal the application window bounds. Subviews of your view should be sized and positioned relative to your ViewController's view.

In the first case, you will end up with an invalid rect and thus an invalid autoresizing mask.

Try this:
_blockerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: self.view.bounds];

Comment: No, i don't call this block of code in viewDidLoad. It's still not working. It should work by setting it a proper autoresizeMask but I'm not figure out how to do that. This class where i set things programatically it's a superclass from which another one inherite and which have IBOutlets of controls. I made a notification-observer mechanism to notify the child class that it has to stop or animate that spinner. (UIActivityIndicatorView dragged directly on the interface builder respond correctly to struts and springs setted in the interface builder)

Comment: A fixed number will not work unless the view's size starts the same every single time. The view's size starts the same size as the UIScreen's bounds, so you need to make sure your origins are derived from the view controller's view's size. @Meeshoo didn't my answer work for you?

Comment: It's working but i'm looking for an scalable solution , not to set position manually.

Comment: @Meeshoo I've edited mine to make it more dynamic. Note that if you want it fixed from the bottom by a certain amount, then obviously that amount needs to be manually used in frame calculations.

Comment: @SomeGuy Ok, thanks, now it's better. I substituted with this line: activityIndictatorFrame.origin.y = _blockerView.frame.size.height - activityIndictatorFrame.size.height - 210; and now this indicator is perfect overlapping over the one I setted in interface builder. I will continue to search for a solution only with autoresizing masks and I will update this thread when i will find one.